# JavaScript delay() function

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript-based modal dialog. The dialog is fading in and fading out fine, but if I want the fadeout to be delayed by some seconds using `delay(3000)`, it is not working. It simply never fades out.  What could I be doing wrong?  It's an MVC app.

```
function testingh(button) {
    alert("DfdfdfF");
    $('.error-notification').remove();
    var $err = $('<div>').addClass('error-notification')
        .html('<h2>Paolo is awesome</h2>(click on this box to close)')
        .css('left', $(button).position().left);
    $(button).after($err);
    $err.fadeIn('slow');
    $err.delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
}
```

If you know of a more efficient way to `delay(meaning postpone)` the fading out, then let me know. Using `delay(3000).fadeOut` seemed most efficient to me?

CSS:

```
.error-notification {
    background-color:#AE0000;
    color:white;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: none;
    padding:15px;
    padding-top: 0;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.error-notification h2 {
    font-family:Trebuchet MS,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:140%;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to debug it? With firebug or any other tool?

Comment: That sequence works just fine in a simple test.  You should post what the CSS looks like, and as @Vinzenz suggests you should use Firebug or some other debug tools to check what the element CSS looks like during the animation.

Comment: I posted CSS. Note:fadeOut on its own does work... it's justt that after "delay" it doesnt fade out at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $err.fadeOut()
}, 3000);
```

Comment: well jQuery supports delay the way he showed it so I would try to figure out first what was wrong with that

Comment: A simple hide().delay(500).show() failed for me a couple days ago. Apparently, it's common across the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
$err.delay(3000).fadeout('slow');
```

try writing

```
$err.fadeout('4000');
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that you have to queue-chain your delay? try this

```
$err.fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: This should make no difference.